# Can set in a metric space be open and have all of its points isolated?

Tags: real-analysis, metric-spaces

I have been going through some questions in my real analysis book and I came to this one.
It says the answer is no, but I think that the set of Natural numbers in the metric space of Natural numbers with |x-y| metric is both open (its the whole space) and all of its points are isolated.

Comment: Yes you are right

Comment: Can you cite the *entire* question?  If the metric space itself has isolated points then those isolated points are themselves open sets.  And you are correct, the space itself is open.  But if the metric space has no isolated points and the metric is the euclidean metric then, no, a set with isolated points isn't open.  But right now, I'm inclined to say you are correct and the  text isn't.... but I'd actually like to read the text and give itself a chance to defend itself.

Comment: @fleablood The question says: What can we say about open sets that have all of its points isolated?
The answer is: There are none.

Comment: That's just wrong. The empty set is open, and all its points are isolated. (And of course, if the space has isolated points, there are also nonempty open sets all of whose points are isolated. But "there are none" is wrong even if we assume the space is perfect.)

Comment: In any metric (or just topological) space, the empty set is open and all its points are isolated.

Comment: "What can we say about open sets that have all of its points isolated? "  Okay, but the book could be assuming we are talking only open the euclidean metric on $\mathbb R$.  The question doesn't say anything about what metric space we are in.  ... Oh, and even then the empty set is such a set as Daniel Fischer points out.... I'm afraid you are too smart for your text.  ... it happens.)

Answer (score 0):

Yes.  Consider any discrete metric space.  That's $d(x,y)=\begin{cases}0,x=y\\1,x\ne y\end{cases}$.

All the sets are then counterexamples.